# Get the string between two digits

Tags: regex, sed

I have string like "a-bd-dgd.16.4.8-123-34-67dd-.ddsfd" I want to get the string between start and end from digit.

So i need 16.4.8-123-34-67 using sed or regex.

I tried -

```
echo "a-bd-dgd.16.4.8-123-34-67dd-.ddsfd" | sed 's/[^0-9.-]//g' | sed 's/[^0-9]*.$//g'
```

Comment: Okay, what have you done to achieve that?

Comment: On SO we encourage users to add their own efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems in their question, so kindly add in your question and let us know then.

Comment: This will get all from first to last digit: `echo "a-bd-dgd.16.4.8-123-34-67dd-.ddsfd" | sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9].*[0-9])[^0-9]*/\1/'`

Comment: That looks like a perfectly good answer @Jotne, why just a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do:

```
echo "a-bd-dgd.16.4.8-123-34-67dd-.ddsfd" | sed -r 's/[^0-9]*([0-9].*[0-9])[^0-9]*/\1/'
16.4.8-123-34-67
```

- `[^0-9]*` marks all non digit
- `([0-9].*[0-9])` makes a group of all data starts with a digit and ends with a digit
- `[^0-9]*` rest of the non digit data
- `\1` point back to the data in the captured group.